# C# exits method when I add item to string array

Tags: c#, winforms, arraylist

I'm struggling to understand why when I add an item to my string array "internalDives", the method exits and there is no debug error shown.

Please, what have I done wrong here?

```
private void GridDataConnection()
{
    using (SqlCeConnection conn = new SqlCeConnection(ConnectionString))
    {
        conn.Open();

        using (SqlCeCommand command = new SqlCeCommand("SELECT id,divelocation,divedate,diveduration FROM loggeddives", conn))
        {
            SqlCeDataReader readDiveResult = command.ExecuteReader();

            var diveList = new List<string[]>();

            while (readDiveResult.Read())
            {
                string[] internalDives = new string[4];

                internalDives[0] = readDiveResult.GetString(0);
                internalDives[1] = readDiveResult.GetString(1);
                internalDives[2] = readDiveResult.GetString(2);
                internalDives[3] = readDiveResult.GetString(3);

                diveList.Add(internalDives);

                i++;
            }
        }

        conn.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Add a try/catch block, and catch the exception message.

Comment: Try and create a string variable for each GetString result and look at them in the debugger also.

Comment: If there aren't 4 columns in the readDiveResult, won't it throw an error?

Comment: why is there an i++; in your while?

Comment: @LouisBoux mistake in replication from VS. Ignore that one.

Comment: As others have said, catch the exception.  I've also had better success using `.getValue(0).ToString()` when nulls showed up.

Comment: @mservidio thanks, a try/catch block give me the clues I needed. Completely forgot about them....... I was using GetString for database fields that required another method. (GetInt64)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure all columns types are string? GetString doesn't make any conversion and suppose all columns are of type string. I suggest you to use a try catch statement for catching any  `InvalidCastException`.

Check also that all values are instanced. You can do it with IsDBNull method.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you should do is absolutely to catch the exception that is being thrown, as mservidio mentioned in comments.

In all likelihood what you will discover when you do is that one of your calls to GetString is throwing an IndexOutOfBoundsException, so be prepared to step through your code carefully and look at what is coming down the Read pipeline.  It might not be what you think it is.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you have null values in your database so, when you try to read one of the columns you get  the error: "Data is Null. This method or property cannot be called on Null values". You must call the IsDBNull method to check if the value is null or not and after that read the value.

try this code

```
private void GridDataConnection()
{
    using (SqlCeConnection conn = new SqlCeConnection(ConnectionString))
    {
        conn.Open();

        using (SqlCeCommand command = new SqlCeCommand("SELECT id,divelocation,divedate,diveduration FROM loggeddives", conn))
        {
            SqlCeDataReader readDiveResult = command.ExecuteReader();

            var diveList = new List<string[]>();

            while (readDiveResult.Read())
            {
                string[] internalDives = new string[4];

                internalDives[0] = readDiveResult.IsDBNull(0) ? "": readDiveResult.GetString(0);
                internalDives[1] = readDiveResult.IsDBNull(1) ? "": readDiveResult.GetString(1);
                internalDives[2] = readDiveResult.IsDBNull(2) ? "": readDiveResult.GetString(2);
                internalDives[3] = readDiveResult.IsDBNull(3) ? "": readDiveResult.GetString(3);

                diveList.Add(internalDives);

                i++;
            }
        }

        conn.Close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I usually validate information coming back from a query before attempting to add it to an array or a list. Do a quick check to verify that all of the values are strings and perhaps even get a count to verify there are 4 values. As others have mentioned a try catch is quite helpful. You can also create a quick error log to dump any exceptions into a temp file.

First answer be gentle!